# DRY, JavaScript Loops and Performance

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dry

I am trying to refactor my code using DRY rules and I am not sure what is the best practice to achieve good performance and clean code.

**Project details and goal:**

My project gets 100 songs from deezer API with details like img, title, svg. I want to pass that data to 10 sections.

**index.html** code:

```
<main>
 <section>1</section>
 <section>2</section>
 <section>3</section>
 <section>4</section> 
 <section>5</section>
 <section>6</section>
 <section>7</section>
 <section>8</section>
 <section>9</section>
 <section>10</section>
</main>
```

**each `section`** should have `ul` and 10 `li` with song details

**each `li`** should have inside nested HTML elements

```
<li>
 <img src="" alt="" />
 <h3>Title song</h3>
 <div class="svg__container">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
    <svg> svg body... </svg>
  </a>
 </div>
</li>
```

My question is what is the best practice to pass that li's to HTML:

1. Just write 100+ li elements in index.html
2. Using Javascript functions with loops and appendChild:

   **index.js**

```
// render ul's
const renderUl = () => {

 const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

 allSections.forEach( (section) => {

 const newUl = document.createElement('ul');
 newUl.appendChild(section);
})
}

// render li's

const renderLi = () => {
 const allUl = document.querySelectorAll('ul');

 allUl.forEach( ul => {
   for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    const newLi = document.createElemenet('li');
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
   }
  })
 }

// then render li Element's

const renderLiElements = () => {
 const allLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');

 allLi.forEach( li => {
   const liElements = 
      `<img src="" alt="" />
       <h3>Title song</h3>
       <div class="svg__container">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
          <svg> svg body... </svg>
        </a>
       </div>`

  li.innerHTML = liElements;
 })
}

//then init all functions
const initApp = () => {
 renderUl();
 renderLi();
 renderLiElemenets();
 }
initApp();
```

*That solution degrades my application performance, but it seems to be more DRY. I am not repeating 100 times same svg and same icons.*

I am 100% sure there is some other way to achieve my goal and don't repeat 100 times same elements. Hope you guys can point me to better solution.

**// EDIT**

*I want to build this app with vanilla js, parcel bundler and babel. Don't want to use any other libraries/frameworks.*

Comment: I don't think one should worry about WET HTML being served - it'll be gzipped, and more JS means more load on the client. But it'll be more maintainable for *you* to use a template engine or something similar server-side.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ... or a template engine clientside, for that matter. (Knockout, Ractive, Vue, whatever).

Comment: Consider using [fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

Comment: @Amadan A template engine clientside would be doing something similar to what OP has already implemented above, resulting in the same sort of *That solution degrades my application performance* he's worried about - except, possibly even worse due to the overhead of the engine, I would think?

Comment: I want to build this app with vanilla js, parcel bundler and  babel. Don't want to use any other libraries/frameworks. 

Just edited post.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Yes, it seems the same — but I'd say I haven't inspected OP's code, nor ran performance profile... while the established engines spent hundreds of man-hours optimising the code. Aaaanyway, just saying it's a possibility, not suggesting to OP that they should do it. If performance is an issue... do it in several ways, and profile it. But most likely, the performance does _not_ matter to that degree.

Comment: Thanks for answer guys. Seems that solution 1. got the best performance but isn't it bad that i repeat 100+ times same  `<svg>` image ? Maybe someone have any other idea.

Comment: Don't append to the DOM directly. Instead of querySelecting() an existing section, start with creating a documentFragment. Append the sections, lists and items to that fragment. Once everything is inside the fragment, append the fragment to the DOM. That will help a little bit. Second part would be to apginate the songs so only the visible ones are rendered immediately.

Comment: @Shilly and @amedina thanks for advice but i have one question:
Should I use nested document.Fragment ? One for `section` one for `ul`'s and one for` li`? Or just one fragment for section and then append ol's. li's and items

Comment: That should matter less ( or nto at all), since neither fragment is rendered yet. So one fragment suffices. I only use a nested fragment if it makes looping the nesting easier. ( like when using array.reduce() to create a list of children. ) By the time you append the final fragment containing all the sections, any nested fragments inside the sections are already gone. The objective is minimizing the amount of times you have to query or change the live, already rendered DOM.